# How can I segment a data array while preserving the original, global coordinate system of each segment?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, coordinates, segment, preserve

I have a matrix that I'm simply trying to segment into equal size patches, while also preserving the coordinate system of each (from their original place in the data file). I need to be able to segment them and then index points on each segment that are still tied to the original, global coordinate system (not the newly created one):

```
from pylab import imshow, show
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(2, size=(70, 70))

lenX = int(70)
lenY = int(70)

def extract_blocks(a, blocksize):
    M,N = a.shape
    b0, b1 = blocksize
    return a.reshape(M//b0,b0,N//b1,b1).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,b0,b1)

#imshow(extract_blocks(image, (int(lenX/2),int(lenY/2)))[0]) #these coordinates are correct
imshow(extract_blocks(image, (int(lenX/2),int(lenY/2)))[1]) #these coords should be x+35
    #...but instead are the same as above
#imshow(extract_blocks(image, (int(lenX/2),int(lenY/2)))[2]) #etc.
#imshow(extract_blocks(image, (int(lenX/2),int(lenY/2)))[3]) #etc.

show()
```

Any help is tremendously appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a `global coordinate system` in `numpy`.  Indexing is based on the `shape` and `strides` attributes, not some sort of index mapping.  You'll have to create and maintain your own coordinates.  For example generate indices with `meshgrid` or `mgrid`, and apply `extract_blocks` to those arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Hmm, very good to know.  thank you so much!